# How to get size of Database in Azure SQL Managed Instance using Azure Management Fluent API?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-managed-instance

Is there any way to get size of database in SQL Managed Instance in Azure using API for Azure management (*Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.dll*)?

Or maybe with another API?

The way of SQL queries is not possible for us, because we cannot connect to SQL Server directly.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Managed Instances - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/2020-08-01-preview/managedinstances/get) API to retrieve information about an instance; which provide response property of size `properties.storageSizeInGB`.

Check this [sample request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/2020-08-01-preview/managedinstances/get#get-managed-instance) for more reference.

Comment: Thank You, good to know. But if I understand, this is storage per whole server, not per database.

Answer (score 0):

we can certainly get details from Azure Metrics. I haven't tried for Managed Instance though.
Please check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/get-azmetric?view=azps-5.7.0

Something like this: (Got from https://fonsecasergio.wordpress.com/2019/03/27/how-to-get-azure-sql-database-size/)

$Databases = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName "GROUPNAME" -ResourceType Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases
foreach ($DB in $Databases)
{
$DBSize = Get-TotalDatabaseSizeKb $DB
"DB ($($DB.Name)) $($DBSize)Kb or $($DBSize / 1024)Mb"
}

Answer (score 0):

Try with this powershell:

```
Get-AzSqlInstance -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroupOfYourSQLMI"
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/get-azsqlinstance?view=azps-5.7.0

and this one:

```
Get-AzSqlInstanceDatabase -InstanceName "managedInstance1" -ResourceGroupName "resourcegroup01"
```